# CKEditor text alignment buttons

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, text-alignment

Is there a way to add the align buttons to the toolbar without downloading the full version of ckeditor?

Thanxx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the [justify plugin](http://ckeditor.com/addon/justify). Also see [official docs](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_plugins).

Comment: I also added the Bidi plugin, but when adding the buttons to the toolbar they are disabled. Do you know why?

Answer (score 3):

Just add `justify` plugin.

```js
config.extraPlugins = "justify";
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution, I found for my `ckeditor 4` version:

https://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/10320

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
                //allowedContent : true
                enterMode : CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR,
                toolbar : [
                ['Font', 'FontSize'], ['TextColor', 'BGColor'], ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike'], ['Subscript', 'Superscript'],
                ['JustifyLeft', 'JustifyRight', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyBlock'], ['NumberedList', 'BulletedList'], ['Outdent', 'Indent', 'Blockquote'], ['Table', 'HorizontalRule', 'SpecialChar'], ['Link', 'Unlink', 'Image'],
                ['Cut', 'Copy', 'Paste', 'PasteText', 'PasteFromWord'], ['Undo', 'Redo', '-', 'Find', 'Replace', '-', 'SelectAll', 'RemoveFormat'], ['Source']
                ]
            } );
```

Just added `['JustifyLeft', 'JustifyRight', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyBlock']` in ckeditor's toolbar and It worked for me like charm. Thanks for asking this question.